# Facebook APIs for Android

Tags: android, facebook

How can we get Facebook APIs for Android?

Comment: which social networking application are you looking for?  did you try their website?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using the following SDK put together as an open source project. You will need to get a facebook api key directly from facebook.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

Comment: Nopes, you do not need any kind of API key, you just need to create an application in Facebook, use the app Id in your code and upload your key-hash on FB application.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on working with Facebook and other APIs in your Android app, you might consider the Temboo SDK which provides normalized access to Facebook and many other APIs. The Android SDK is an open download (https://www.temboo.com/download) although you'll need a (free) Temboo account to do anything with it.

(Full disclosure: I work at Temboo)